# Giving Namespace in javascript file when a assignment statement is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of javascript code for which i want to add a namespace. In this code there is an assignment operation taking place which outside the functions. Could someone please tell me how to put this in a namespace? The Code is given below.

```
var mynameSpace={
canvasPanel:{},
stage:{},
someShape:{},

drawLineGraph:function(dataList,color,baseY)
{
//Create a shape
this.dataList=dataList;
this.index=0;
this.currentDay=1;
},

myNameSpace.drawLineGraph.prototype = new createjs.Shape(); //Getting the problem here
myNameSpace.drawLineGraph.prototype.constructor = drawLineGraph; //Getting the problem here**
,
drawLegend:function(){
}

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the function and subsequent assignments in another function, then call it immediately, like this:

```
drawLineGraph: (function() {
   var f = function(dataList, color, baseY {
       // Create a shape
          ... function code ...
   };
   f.prototype = new createjs.Shape();
     ... more assignments ...

   return f; // this will be assigned to drawLineGraph
})(),
```

Comment: Thanks artem for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `drawLineGraph` with `this.drawLineGraph`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're doing the prototype assignments inside the object literal definition. So the drawLineGraph property of mynameSpace doesn't exist when you try to modify it's prototype. Move the drawLineGraph prototype property assignments below the object literal.

```
var mynameSpace={
    canvasPanel:{},
    stage:{},
    someShape:{},

    drawLineGraph:function(dataList,color,baseY)
        {
        //Create a shape
        this.dataList=dataList;
        this.index=0;
        this.currentDay=1;
    },

    drawLegend:function(){
    }

};
myNameSpace.drawLineGraph.prototype = new createjs.Shape(); //No longer a problem
myNameSpace.drawLineGraph.prototype.constructor = drawLineGraph; //No longer a problem
```